# I have a DoFollow backlink but I can't go directly to my site without a confirmation to leave it

Tags: googlebot, dofollow

I have a DoFollow backlink to a forum and I checked it. My concern is before I can reach my site using that link, there is a message:

> You're leaving the site, are you sure you wanted to continue?

How about if Googlebot will try to crawl the site and see that it is pointing to my site? Does Googlebot also click the confirmation that it will be leaving the site? Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: Why are you concerned? and can you give an example of the page that directs as depends on how that is setup.

Answer (score 2):

Largely I would say your worry is about nothing for two reasons:

1. **If it is a big forum:**
   Google will know it is a forum an therefor backlinks from the forum are considered low quality.
2. **If it is a small forum:**
   Google will not have a high regard for this website no matter where the link is.

Technically speaking, I don't think Googlbot would literally click the links, it will pull the HTML out of the page. But if it is redirecting you the link, it may well actually be to an internal redirect page, thus no link to your website will be found.